# How do I find the tile I'm standing on?

Tags: java, 2d, tiles

I want to get the specific tile I am standing on. My Tiles are in an `Arraylist` so I can destroy them later. How can I do this?

Here's my `Level`-class (where my `List`s are):

```
public class Level {
    public int width,height;
    public int xScrool,yScrool;

    private Mouse mouse;

    public Random random;
    public List<Tile> tiles;
    public List<Entity> entities;

    public Level(int width,int height,int xs,int ys,Mouse mouse)
    {
        this.xScrool = xs;
        this.yScrool = ys;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.mouse = mouse;
        entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        random = new Random ();
        generate();
    }

    public void setScrool(int xScrool,int yScrool)
    {
        this.xScrool = xScrool;
        this.yScrool = yScrool;
    }

    private void generate ()
    {
        int Row = -1;
        for(int y = 0; y < height;y++)
        {
            int RandomHeight = random.nextInt (3);
            for(int x = 0; x < width;x++)
            {
                tiles.add ( new Tile_Dirt ( Sprite.dirtTile,x,RandomHeight) ); // This is where the tiles get added to my list
            }
        }
    }

    public void init(Level level)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < entities.size ();i++)
        {
            entities.get ( i ).init (level);
        }
    }

    public void update()
    {
        if(mouse.getMouseB () == 1)
        {

        }


        for(int i = 0;i < entities.size ();i++)
        {
            entities.get ( i ).update ();
        }

    }

    public void render(int xScrool,int yScrool,Screen screen)
    {
        screen.setOffset ( xScrool,yScrool );
        for(int i = 0; i < tiles.size (); i++)
        {
            tiles.get (i).render (screen);
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < entities.size ();i++)
        {
            entities.get ( i ).render (screen);
        }
    }


    public Tile getTile(int x,int y)
    {
        return tiles.get (  ); // I have no clue how i can gonna make this one
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to GD:SE! There is not enough information here to actually answer your question. Maybe include your code that you've tried and we can help you further from there!

Comment: How about iterating through the tiles and checking for each tile whether it's just below your character? How much programming experience do you have?

Comment: Updated my Question

Comment: Hi Robert. That's a lot of code. It's hard for us to read and go through all of it. Maybe only including the relevant bits would help?

Answer (score 1):

You're not even using the `y` coordinate when you're storing your tiles. You're just using `x` and some random value: `( Sprite.dirtTile,x,RandomHeight)'. Which likely means you'll have tiles stacked on top of each other, meaning your list is going to contain some tiles that are occupying the same position.

However, the naive approach to finding the tile at a specific `x, y`, given how you're storing your tiles, is to iterate through the list until you find a tile matching those coordinates.

```
public Tile getTile(int x,int y)
{
    for(Tile tile : tiles) {
       if(tile.x == x && tile.y == y)
          return tile;
    }
    //We didn't find a tile matching that position
    return null;
}
```

Granted, if there are duplicates, this likely won't find the one you're seeing on screen. Since you're drawing tiles by iterating through the list, this means in the case of duplicates, the *last* instance of a tile will be drawn over the others. The code above will find the *first* instance of a tile at a specific position.

All in all,  I suggest you try again with this code. Rewrite it with the requirement of accessing an arbitrary position in mind. Think about how a two dimensional array might help in that situation. Also consider how you're placing tiles and if they're actually ending up where you want them to.

Comment: This code has some very old and ugly solutions. I gonna rewrite it soon.Ty for your help this should work